# Why can't I look through this array that is type object?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, arrayobject

I am trying to look at specific items (strings) in the object array and parse the strings but the **error at weekData.at(i) says "expression must have class type but it has type "WeekData *" "**.

```
double Stats::GetMean(WeekData weekData[], int num){
    vector<string> dateV;
    vector<int> deathV;
    double mean = 0;
    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<num;i++){
        string line = weekData.at(i); **//ERROR**
        stringstream ss(line);
        while(ss.good()) {
            string week;
            string death;
            getline(ss, week, ',');
            getline(ss, death, ',');
            int deaths = atoi(death.c_str());
            dateV.push_back(week);
            deathV.push_back(deaths);
            total = total+deaths;
        }
    }
   return mean = total/num;
}
```

The error at weekData.at(i) says "expression must have class type but it has type "WeekData *" ".

Comment: Just use square brackets. It’s an array, not a vector

Comment: Tip: `const std::vector<WeekData>&` is a lot more convenient.

Comment: `total` is an `int`, which is probably wrong. You're working with `double` results, so why not `double` out of the gate? Plus: `total += deaths` is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

You passed weekData in as an array type in `WeekData weekData[]`. Which is equivalent to passing in a pointer to the first element of an array like `WeekData *`.

So at this line

```
string line = weekData.at(i);
```

The compiler sees a pointer to a WeekData object, tries to use the `.` dot operator on it, and fails. The line you need is.

```
string line = weekData[i];
```